# htaccess not working with categories

Tags: php, .htaccess, categories

At the moment i have the following url

www.mydomain.com/categories.php?id=actions

but i want it to look like

www.mydomain.com/categories/actions

I have tryed the following but its saying page not found. What am i doing wrong?

here is the .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^categories/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ categories.php?id=$1
```

And here is the php

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
   $id = $_GET['id'];

   if($id == 'all'){
     echo "all";
   } else if($id == 'actions'){
     echo "actions";
   }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try without the trailing slash (because in your question, there is not, but your rule is waiting for a trailing slash, so it does not match):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^categories/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ categories.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: opps, Thanks this sorted it :)